# Determine the amount of energy used for baking a cake

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, energy, home-experiment, estimation

Let's suppose we have a room of temperature $T_0$ with an oven of volume $V$, both filled with air of density $\rho$ and specific heat $c$. We need to bake a cake in the temperature $T_1$. Thus we heat the oven to the temperature $T_1$ (it takes the time $t_1$) and keep this temperature through time $t >> t_1$. (A real-life example: $t=90 \mathrm{min}, t_1=8 \mathrm{min}, T_0 = 20^\circ C, T_1 = 190 ^\circ C$ )

I'd like to determine the amount of energy spent on baking the cake. Of course I could measure the total power consumption with oven on and off and subtract these values, but this method isn't really accurate (I can't guarantee that the power usage of the other devices is really constant - too many factors there). Is there a better method?

Comment: What's the weight loss of the cake? That's the least amount of energy that you need just to evaporate the water in it. There is, of course, the chemistry of baking, which I don't know anything about...

Comment: I don't know, but it can be measured easily. But I suspect the most energy is spent on keeping the very high temperature.

Comment: if the total consumption doesn't make sense for you, perhaps you can do the measures with one cake and then with two. Don't forget to measure the residual heats.

Comment: Yes, but $Q_{used} = Q_{cake} + Q_{air}$. So measuring this would be even worse. Besides, I would have to measure the total heat nevertheless. I though about determining the heat losses since $Q_{total} \approx P_{loss} (t_1 + t) + Q_{water in cake} + Q_{heat}$ (in fact it will be a little less)

Comment: shut down all the electric devices in the house , cook and measure the consumption at the electricity meter. Or install one behind the oven.

Comment: A well insulated industrial oven is actually quite power efficient, your oven at home, of course, is not, and there is little you can change about that because of the poor ratio between the content you cook and the size of the oven. A better example would probably be a bread-maker, where the size of the oven is pretty much the size of the "bread", which technically is not bread, of course, but just a loaf-cake.